# How to get the latest home feeds each time only the latest

Tags: c++, facebook-graph-api

im using the

```
https://graph.facebook.com/me/home
```

every N seconds to get my home feeds , but now i like to get each iteration only the latest not all of them what will be the best way to do it ? 
Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use the timestamp that comes back with the first result and then use ?since=xxxxx on the next request  (See "paging" section on https://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/api/)

Comment: what is the last date , the updated_time or the created_time that returns and which paramter the since compare with

Comment: Play with it using the graph API explorer tool.  You'll find out quickly enough.  Plus it gives you more time exploring the API which is always a good thing.  Can you please mark this answer as accepted if it solved your issue?